# is there Python client API for 'kubectl auth can-i --list'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to list permissions associated to a service account 'foobar-user' applied to my cluster in namespace 'kube-system':

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:kube-system:foobar-user --namespace=kube-system

Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names     Verbs
clusterroles                                    []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
deployments                                     []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
endpoints                                       []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
pods                                            []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
rolebindings                                    []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
roles                                           []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
secrets                                         []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
services                                        []                                    []                 [create list update watch get]
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                                    []                 [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                                    []                 [create]
                                                [/.well-known/openid-configuration]   []                 [get]
                                                [/api/*]                              []                 [get]
                                                [/api]                                []                 [get]
                                                [/apis/*]                             []                 [get]
                                                [/apis]                               []                 [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                 [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []                 [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                 [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []                 [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]                          []                 [get]
                                                [/openapi]                            []                 [get]
                                                [/openid/v1/jwks]                     []                 [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                 [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []                 [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                 [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []                 [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                 [get]
                                                [/version]                            []                 [get]
nodes                                           []                                    []                 [list watch get]
```

What is an equivalent API to do this through Python client for kubernetes to list permissions associated to a service account? Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Any question of "kubectl does this, but what is the API for it?" is answered by dialing up the verbosity as `kubectl --v=100 auth can-i` and then mimicking its HTTP requests using the API binding of your choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent API to do this through Python client for kubernetes is:

[AuthorizationV1Api - create a SelfSubjectRulesReview](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AuthorizationV1Api.md#create_self_subject_rules_review)

The official Kubernetes docs is as follows:

**`SelfSubjectRulesReview`**: A review which returns the set of actions a user can perform within a namespace. Useful for users to quickly summarize their own access, or for UIs to hide/show actions.

[Checking API Access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried and have a script which calls the API but I get an HTTP 400 Bad Request error the message:

"SelfSubjectAccessReview in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a SelfSubjectAccessReview: v1.SelfSubjectAccessReview.Spec: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found \", error found in #10 byte of ...|{\"spec\": \"foo-bar|..., bigger context ...|{\"spec\": \"foo-bar\"}|..."

Any idea on why the request is malformed?

Comment: @KGosalia I think the error msg says it clear: `"SelfSubjectAccessReview in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a SelfSubjectAccessReview: v1.SelfSubjectAccessReview.Spec: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found \"`, the `spec` part should be a json object, not string.

Comment: I see but it is already a python dict. Here's my code snippet:
spec = {"namespace": "foo-bar"}
with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = kubernetes.client.AuthorizationV1Api(api_client)
    body = kubernetes.client.V1SelfSubjectAccessReview(spec=spec)
    api_response = api_instance.create_self_subject_access_review(body)
    pprint(api_response)
body = {'api_version': None,
 'kind': None,
 'metadata': None,
 'spec': 'foo-bar',
 'status': None}

Comment: With that I hit the below error:
".authorization.k8s.io \"\" is invalid: spec.resourceAttributes: Invalid value: \"null\": exactly one of nonResourceAttributes or resourceAttributes must be specified"

Comment: @KGosalia Your spec dict is still invalid, it should look like the object described here: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1SelfSubjectAccessReviewSpec.md

Comment: Thanks, figured it out! The request was missing keyworded args